# TYPO3 Extbase - Manipulating TCA (using Signal Slot / Hook) after it has been cached - possible?

Tags: model-view-controller, typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

I'm trying to manipulate mainly the TCA array (a domain model its "showitem"-value) mainly because those tabs which can be defined (`--div--;locallang`) can't have a displayCond - so I've added a normal condition which gets the value of a select-tag by the`$_POST` parameters and trying to change this "showitem"-value in the necessary part of the `$GLOBALS["TCA"]-array`.

The problem is now: The TCA gets cached in the cache_core-directory of the typo3temp folder - and disabling entire cache ain't a solution at all.

So what am I supposed to do, since I want to have generally this displayCond on those tabs in my TCA (NOTE: using domain model).

`Used TYPO3 Version: 8.7.29`

I hope there's a solution to that.
Greets.

Was sitting on that problem for hours and tried using signal slots/hooks and inside the TCA file itself - all results the same: TCA cached.

I expect the signal slot/hook gets always called, so I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 years (and some more experience using TYPO3) there are 2 known solutions;

1. Adding a `displayCond` to all fields for each tab since TYPO3 will automatically hide a tab if there are no fields to be displayed.
2. In TYPO3 10.4.20 there's the `AfterTcaCompilationEvent` (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Hooks/Events/Core/Configuration/AfterTcaCompilationEvent.html) which could be useful in such an use-case.